# Python_Selenium - Checking if an element exists and if exists, click it

Tags: python, list, selenium, if-statement, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a code in python with selenium.
Sometimes due to site error a pop-up alike alert [java script] shows up and I have to click alert. I want to program it so every time I click "next Button" to check if the item popped up. If the button had popped up, it should click it.

thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the use of `driver.find_elements` method.
As following:

```py
close_alert_btn = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "locator_of_alert_close_btn")
if close_alert_btn:
    close_alert_btn[0].click()
```

`driver.find_elements` method return a list of matching elements i.e. in case there were found elements matching the passed locator it will return a non-empty list. Non-empty list is interpreted by Python as a Boolean True.
While in case of no match found it will return an empty list interpreted by Python as Boolean False.